# select two distinct columns with flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: sql, python-2.7, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my first Flask project and I am trying to stick to MVC and not just start writing SQL which is proving difficult.  Converting this simple query to Flask-SQLAlchemy is a puzzle I am currently unable to solve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT gradelevel, beginningorendtest 
FROM wordlist 
ORDER BY gradelevel,beginningorendoftest
```

I appreciate any ideas, it may not be possible with Flask-SQLAlchemy. Here is my latest attempt.

```
data = wordlist.query.add_columns(wordlist.gradelevel, wordlist.beginningorendtest).distinct()
print (data)    
for row in data:
    print ("Gradelevel:" + row.gradelevel + " BeginningorEndoftest:" + row.beginningorendtest)
```

Answer (score 1):

After mangling it for awhile, this:

```
 data = wordlist.query.with_entities(wordlist.gradelevel, wordlist.beginningorendtest)
        .distinct().order_by(wordlist.gradelevel).order_by(wordlist.beginningorendtest)
```

will produce this equivalent query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT wordlist.gradelevel AS wordlist_gradelevel,wordlist.beginningorendtest AS wordlist_beginningorendtest 
 FROM wordlist ORDER BY wordlist.gradelevel, wordlist.beginningorendtest
```